# Google Maps API -> Jquery Expandable Map and browser issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been developing a page with Google Map API v3 and have a quick question.  Basically I am using jquery to hide/show the map panels (MAP_HOLDER) and the problem is this:

-> In Firefox the map canvas was not correctly populated by the API, it populated only about 1/5 of the tiles (looked like the last 1/5 of the expected map).  Anyway to resolve this I added this code to the "expand" function in jquery:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

-> Now my main problem, if I do nothing else, the map is displayed correctly in I.E however it is incorrectly displayed in Firefox and Chrome.  Has anyone else experienced this, I can "fix" it by changing the coordinates but this obviously reverses the issue and makes I.E incorrect.

I have tried adding a timeout to the "slideDown()" but this didn't help with anything...

Thanks,
Alex

EDIT, more information> I am developing this in a RAD platform and as such it will be difficult for me to make the code available.  However the map is based within two div's, the outer div and the map-canvas.  I am expanding/collapsing the outer div with the jquery.  The jquery code is simply:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MAP_HOLDER").hide();
    $("#hideMap").hide();
});

collapse = function (element) {
    $("#MAP_HOLDER").slideUp();
    $("#hideMap").hide();
    $("#showMap").show();
}

expand = function (element) {
    $("#hideMap").show();
    $("#showMap").hide();
    $("#MAP_HOLDER").slideDown();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); // resize map
    var position = map.getcentre();
    map.setCentre(position);
}
```

The map api code:

```
// Set look and feel of the maps
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

// Create some variables for our map elements
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var marker;
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat_goes_here, lng_goes_here),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// A function to run at page load
function init() {
    //location on form here:
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    //set marker image here
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    marker.setTitle("stuff");
    // Add a function to run on the "click" event
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        document.getElementById("pos_lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById("pos_lng").value = event.latLng.lng();
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()));
    });
}
```

I edited it a bit so ignore any basic typo's please.  I haven't copied CSS into this but I do have the following applied to the (there is a bit more to it) MAP_HOLDER div:

```
overflow:hidden;
z-index:-999;
```

The whole thing working! http://jsfiddle.net/n34_panda/gNdLV/

Comment: There is not sufficient info here to be able to help you. Give us a working example that shows the issue and tell us more about the *incorrectly displayed* issue.

Comment: Cheers,  the incorrectly displayed issue was due to the div originally set as hidden when the page loads.  Once the jquery expands the panel the map was not correctly filling the tiles.  This image is very similar to what I experience, note how it doesn't centre properly:
-> http://i.stack.imgur.com/YaFZR.jpg
This link is similar to my problem
->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949167/google-maps-does-not-render-correctly-in-ie8-within-iframe-nyromodal-layer

I will try and expand my original post to explain it in more detail

Comment: Good. If you can do a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that would be great.

Comment: I've updated my post, hopefully a bit more info.  I haven't included the CSS because, well, the RAD platform is a bit "clunky" and I can't see an easy way of dragging it all out - I am a bit new to all this so bare with me.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the map resize as a callback of your `.show()` function.

Something like that:

```
function showMap() {

    $("#MAP_HOLDER").show(resizeMap);
}

function resizeMap() {

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}
```

Here is a <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/uX63Q/9/)</kbd> to demonstrate.

I tested it with IE and Chrome and both work like a charm. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it is resizing as expected however it does not centre on the co-ords set in the options...this is working in I.E but not in Chrome/Firefox...I can change the co-ords but then I.E would not work thanks!

Comment: Right. What about *resetting* the center? See my updated fiddle.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that, see the original post pretty basic - I am trying to create a fiddle just now but the css is causing havoc from the RAD.  I am wondering if the css is causing the problem...

Comment: Did you try my updated fiddle? Works fine for me on both browsers. Or I don't get what's wrong on your side...

Comment: Hi, yes thanks.  i tried without success.  Sorry about the responses I was trying to get fiddle to properly replicate the error...it wasn't easy but I am beginning to get there.  it isn't 100% accurate as in my development environment I can actually resize correctly, it is just not re-centering on Chrome/Firefox.  Anyway take a look here, I implemented the jquery too:http://jsfiddle.net/uX63Q/

Comment: But you didn't implement what I tried in my fiddle... Anyway, I corrected a few errors in your code, now what about it? http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/uX63Q/5/

Comment: Thanks, I see I was missing a crucial aspect of fiddle in my testing....anyway, your fiddle replicates the same issue I am experiencing  - the map is not centred on the specified location once expanded (I tested in firefox and chrome (both fiddles) and they are both incorrect) - does it look ok on yours?  The city should be centred

EDIT-> I am very grateful for your help!!!

Comment: Right. I didn't see that. I was focused on the resize. Can't you just reuse the `center` variable to reset the center? http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/uX63Q/9/

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your code and it doesn't work on my fiddle (I have checked the api's and extensions and they look fine).  To get mine to work, I was required to make the edits in expand() and resizeMap().  Reckon we have spent enough time on this, I feel sorry for you, must be like talking to a child!

Comment: No worries. But does it work now? If yes, don't forget to accept the answer. If not, I'll be happy to help further.

Comment: Yes, it will do.  I will need to write a little extra to account for the users moving the maps (so it centre's) on their last position and doesn't reset if they continually expand/collapse the panel...I think I can get it now - thanks!  I'll mark the post above as answered

Comment: Right I understand the issue -  So the map is initialised on page load, however it is hidden so the map isn't correctly centred.  When the user chooses to expand it it isn't centred (except in i.e).  I want it to be correctly centred on initialisation, when the user resizes it using the expand/collapse It should use getCenter() before setCentre.  I hope that makes sense, just a matter of that small issue now: My fiddle should display this : http://jsfiddle.net/uX63Q/

Comment: I have been further fiddling, if you remove the line  $("#map-canvas").hide(); from the document.ready it works! I clearly need to initiliase the map some other way - perhaps on page load? Or first click of "show map" only?  does that make sense?

Comment: What is the last version of your fiddle?

Comment: Morning!  If you take a look at this one, I have a few other versions but this is most "like" what I am forced to use in the RAD environment. http://jsfiddle.net/uX63Q/15/

Comment: Sorry, I gave you a few hints in my fiddles but I see nothing implemented there. Plus there are weird things in your code. Why use a window load event in the init that calls init? Why is the map resize only in a window resize event? I am lost as to where you want to go.

Comment: I meant to remove the windows load with init...the resize on window resize event was a suggested solution to the problem - it doesn't work.  This fiddle is updated, I did try implementing resize as a function instead within the showMap but it just mimic's the same behaviour so I removed it temporarily: http://jsfiddle.net/uX63Q/16/

Comment: The window resize event will only fire when you actually resize the browser window. Go back to my fiddle and try to understand the callback function for the slideDown. I think that's the way you should go.

Comment: Many thanks, I think I have got it working, a combination of your method and map.getCenter();  http://jsfiddle.net/uX63Q/18/

Comment: Took long enough didn't it!  I really appreciate it